# Cleaning project broke R

Tags: android, eclipse

I had some problems with R in one of my Android projects, so I tried Eclipse->Project->Clean. I foolishly did it for all of my projects (what's the harm, right?). Now Eclipse throws a warning for every last reference to R, and refuses to build anything. Build All does not do anything. Help please!

EDIT: I just noticed that this is similar to:
Link
[Clean in Eclipse temporarily destroys Android project with error message: missing required source folder: 'gen'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820517/clean-in-eclipse-temporarily-destroys-android-project-with-error-message-missin)

Perhaps for those that fiddling with Build Automatically does not help, the above will help.

I did not get this particular error message, though.

Comment: Reopen Eclipse helps me in such issue, or you can try to uncheck and check again Build Automatically

Comment: Messing around with the Build Automatically checkbox did fix things. Darned if I know how. IDE voodoo is terrrible. Thanks! I guess you can add it as an answer, so I can mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reopen Eclipse helps me in such issue, or you can try to uncheck and check again Build Automatically.